# Python 2.7 mechanize library

Tags: python

I am trying to use mechanize to access a website and submit form to login. My end goal is to login to a ticketing system, fill in the required  fields and submit which in turn would generate a ticket number which I need to grab.

I have the following code.

```
import urllib
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Firefox')]
br.set_handle_robots(False)
jira='jira_link'
br.open(jira)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['os_username'] = 'username'
br.form['os_password']=  'password'
sub=br.submit()
print sub.geturl()
```

However I get the following error when I run the script

```
raise BrowserStateError("not viewing HTML")
```

mechanize._mechanize.BrowserStateError: not viewing HTML

I successfully logged into Facebook using the same code.
Checking browser console it does look like a valid html doc.